# avoiding duplicate database calls to generate metadata in next 13/14

Tags: javascript, next.js

Next 13 and 14 introduced the [generateMetadata](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/generate-metadata) function as the recommended way to set all page metadata.

The only issue with this is that – as a result of the logic being separated – data based on fields from a backend require *two* calls to be made, instead of just one.

Consider the following `page.tsx`:

```
export default async function ProfilePage(props){
    try{
        const profile = await prisma.users.findUnique({
            // ... fetch user data
        });

        return <div>Profile page</div>;
    } catch(err){
        notFound();
    }
}

export async function generateMetadata(params){
    const profile = await prisma.users.findUnique({
        // ... fetch user data
    });

    return {
        title: `${profile.name}'s Profile`,
    };
}
```

This requires me to fetch the same information *twice*.

How can I achieve the same results without a duplicate fetch? I want to avoid using `document.title` as this results in a jarring experience when executing it on nested pages.

Answer (score 0):

> The only issue with this is that – as a result of the logic being separated – data based on fields from a backend require two calls to be made, instead of just one.

**Solution :**

> Write your  `await prisma.users.findUnique` inside a async function which is wrapped in `cache() function` provided by react in that page & return data from it. Then just call that function, `const profile = await Function()`. As the function is cached & its called on same page twice NextJS prevents duplication of calls.

**An example code I made :**
**Folder Structure :**

```
projectName
├── src
│   └── app
│       ├── api
│       ├── favicon.ico
│       ├── globals.css
│       ├── layout.js
│       └── user
│           ├── page.js
│           └── [id]
│               └── page.js
└── tailwind.config.js
```

**Explaination :**

- There is a page `/user` it shows all users, & when you click on any user it takes you to details page `/user/user_id` on this page server-side we generate metadata & set user data to page by making a API call.
- There are two calls, one is using cache, & another is commented out. Uncomment anyone at a time & see the result.

**Users Page** `projectName\src\app\user\page.js` *(this page just make a call & gets users list)* :

```
import Link from "next/link";

const AllUsers = async () => {
    let tmp = await fetch('https://dummyjson.com/users')
    let data = await tmp.json()
    return data.users
}

export default async function Page() {

    let AllUserData = await AllUsers();
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Users Page</h1>
            <ol>
                {
                    AllUserData.map((u, i) => (
                        <li key={i}>
                            <Link href={'/user/' + u.id}> {u.firstName}</Link>
                        </li>
                    ))
                }
            </ol>
        </div>
    )
}

export async function generateMetadata() {

    let UserDetails = await AllUsers()
    return {
        title: UserDetails.length.toString() + " Users",
    };
}
```

**User details page** `projectName\src\app\user\[id]\page.js` :

```
import React from 'react'
import { cache } from 'react'

const GetUserByID = cache(async (ID) => {
    console.log(ID);
    // VISIBLE IN TERMINAL
    console.log("GetUserByID HIT (cached) : ", new Date().toLocaleTimeString());
    let tmp = await fetch('https://dummyjson.com/user/' + ID)
    let data = await tmp.json()
    return data

})


// TO RUN BELOW CODE & COMMENT THE ABOVE CODE
// WITHOUT ANY CACHING , THIS CODE RUNS TWICE


// const GetUserByID = async (ID) => {
//     console.log(ID);
//     console.log("GetUserByID HIT : ", new Date().toLocaleTimeString());
//   // VISIBLE IN TERMINAL

//     let tmp = await fetch('https://dummyjson.com/user/' + ID)
//     let data = await tmp.json()
//     return data
// }

export async function generateMetadata({ params }) {

    let UserDetails = await GetUserByID(params.id)
    return {
        title: UserDetails.firstName + " " + UserDetails.lastName,
    };
}

const UserDetailsPage = async ({ params }) => {
    let UserDetails = await GetUserByID(params.id)
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>UserDetailsPage </h1>
            <p>ID Received from params :{params.id} </p>
            <hr />
            <p>ID from data : {UserDetails.id}</p>
            <p>FirstName : {UserDetails.firstName}</p>
            <p>LastName : {UserDetails.lastName}</p>
            <p>Age : {UserDetails.age}</p>
            <p>Birth Day : {UserDetails.birthDate}</p>
        </div>
    )
}

export default UserDetailsPage
```

**Output :**

- Go to `http://localhost:3000/user`, this page has metadata title set equal to number of users calculated from API data. It shows users as links, click to see specific user details has API 2 calls, one uses cache & 2nd does not.
- On details page `http://localhost:3000/user/user_id` , in terminal you will see cache wrapped api call executes only once, & the other one when uncommented it runs twice.

***Please Read :***

- **Data Fetching, Caching, and Revalidating :**  [https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching-caching-and-revalidating](https://%5Bhttps://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching-caching-and-revalidating)
- **Caching in Next.js** : https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/caching
- **Cache function :** https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching-caching-and-revalidating#example
- **Caching Data :** https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching-caching-and-revalidating#caching-data
- **cache** : https://react.dev/reference/react/cache

> ***If you still have any doubts, leave a comment(I will update answer if required)***